# Error in code or formulae converting SVG elliptical arc to HTML5 Canvas arc()?

Tags: svg, html5-canvas, linear-algebra

I'm trying to convert [SVG elliptical arc path commands](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands) into a center point, start/stop angle, and possible scale/rotation (in the case of ellipses).

I'm following the equations in the SVG implementation notes for *[Conversion from Endpoint to Center Parameterization](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/implnote.html#ArcConversionEndpointToCenter)*, but mostly I'm not getting good values. See snippet below, where changing the input values will draw an SVG arc in red, and then attempt to draw the same arc on an HTML5 canvas in green.

I'm pretty sure that I need to correct for out-of-range radii still, and I know that I don't yet handle ellipses (instead of circles), but even when the radii are the same and correct, my code is returning incorrect start/end values.

Can anyone see an error in my conversion from the equations listed in the SVG spec, or an error in the equations themselves?

```js
const { mat2, vec2 } = this.vmath || require('vmath');
[].forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('#x1in,#y1in,#x2in,#y2in,#ƒain,#ƒsin,#rxin,#ryin,#φin'),
  inp => { inp.addEventListener('input',recalc,false) }
);
recalc();

function recalc() {
  const x1=x1in.value*1, y1=y1in.value*1,
        x2=x2in.value*1, y2=y2in.value*1,
        ƒa=ƒain.value*1, ƒs=ƒsin.value*1,
        rx=rxin.value*1, ry=ryin.value*1,
        φ=φin.value*1;

 path.setAttribute('d',['M',x1,y1,'A',rx,ry,φ,ƒa,ƒs,x2,y2].join(' '));

  // F.6.5.1
  const cosφ = Math.cos(φ*Math.PI/180),
        sinφ = Math.sin(φ*Math.PI/180);
  const tmpM2 = mat2.new(cosφ, -sinφ, sinφ, cosφ);
  const cp = vec2.new((x1-x2)/2, (y1-y2)/2);
  vec2.transformMat2(cp,cp,tmpM2);
  const x1p=cp.x, y1p=cp.y;
  x1po.innerHTML = x1p;
  y1po.innerHTML = y1p;

  // F.6.5.2
  vec2.set(cp, rx*y1p/ry, -ry*x1p/rx);
  const rx2=rx*rx, ry2=ry*ry, x1p2=x1p*x1p, y1p2=y1p*y1p;
  vec2.scale(cp, cp, (ƒa==ƒs?-1:1) * Math.sqrt(
   (rx2*ry2 - rx2*y1p2 - ry2*x1p2) /
    (rx2*y1p2 + ry2*x1p2)
  ));
  cpxo.innerHTML = cp.x;
  cpyo.innerHTML = cp.y;
  
  // F.6.5.3
  mat2.set(tmpM2, cosφ, sinφ, -sinφ, cosφ);
  const c = vec2.transformMat2(vec2.new(),cp,tmpM2);
  c.x += (x1+x2)/2;
  c.y += (y1+y2)/2;
  cxo.innerHTML = c.x;
  cyo.innerHTML = c.y;

  const v1 = vec2.new(( x1p-cp.x)/rx, ( y1p-cp.y)/ry);
  const v2 = vec2.new((-x1p-cp.x)/rx, (-y1p-cp.y)/ry);

  // F.6.5.5
  const θ1 = angleBetween( vec2.new(1,0), v1 );
  θ1o.innerHTML = θ1*180/Math.PI;

  // F.6.5.6
  const Δθ = angleBetween( v1, v2 ) % (Math.PI*2);
  Δθo.innerHTML = Δθ*180/Math.PI;

  let ctx=can.getContext('2d');
  // TODO: φ rotation(?) and scaling if rx!=ry
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,400,200);
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,255,0,1)';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(c.x, c.y, rx, θ1, θ1-Δθ, false);
  ctx.stroke();
}

// F.6.5.4
function angleBetween(u,v) {
 const sign = (u.x*v.y - u.y*v.x > 1) ? 1 : -1;
  return sign * Math.acos( vec2.dot(u,v)/vec2.length(u)/vec2.length(v) );
}
```

```css
svg, canvas { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:400px; height:200px }
svg path { fill:none; stroke:red; stroke-width:4px }
#ui { margin-top:200px }
div { margin-bottom:0.5em }
label { margin-right:1em; white-space:nowrap }
input { width:2.5em; text-align:right }
span { font-family:sans-serif }
img { display:block; margin:2em }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/gamedev-js/vmath/1.3.1/dist/vmath.dev.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 400 200">
  <path id="path" d="M0,0 L200,200"/>
</svg>
<canvas id="can" width="400" height="200"></canvas>

<div id="ui">
<div>
<label>x1: <input id="x1in" value="30" type="number" step="1"></label>
<label>y1: <input id="y1in" value="30" type="number" step="1"></label>
<label>x2: <input id="x2in" value="47" type="number" step="1"></label>
<label>y2: <input id="y2in" value="47" type="number" step="1"></label>
<label>ƒa: <input id="ƒain" value="1" type="number" step="1" min="0" max="1"></label>
<label>ƒs: <input id="ƒsin" value="1" type="number" step="1" min="0" max="1"></label>
<label>rx: <input id="rxin" value="17" type="number" step="1"></label>
<label>ry: <input id="ryin" value="17" type="number" step="1"></label>
<label>φ: <input id="φin" value="0" type="number" step="1"></label>
</div>
<div>
<label>x<sub>1</sub>ʹ: <span id="x1po"></span></label>
<label>y<sub>1</sub>ʹ: <span id="y1po"></span></label>
<label>c<sub>x</sub>ʹ: <span id="cpxo"></span></label>
<label>c<sub>y</sub>ʹ: <span id="cpyo"></span></label>
</div>
<div>
<label>c<sub>x</sub>: <span id="cxo"></span></label>
<label>c<sub>y</sub>: <span id="cyo"></span></label>
<label>θ<sub>1</sub>: <span id="θ1o"></span></label>
<label>∆θ: <span id="Δθo"></span></label>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jdvrrw5t/4/

Comment: is this any help? https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/svg/SVGPathData.cpp#646

Comment: @RobertLongson Might do, thanks!